# Regex Stop capture repeated Tags

Tags: java, regex

I have problem in capturing the SSN based on Tags(multiple words) reading before and after. The field is freetext user can enter SSN in any format. In the below input I have 2 different format XXX-XXX-XXX and XX-XXXXXXX.

Input String:

```
Hi i'm John my SSN is 111-111-111, then my wife 222-222-222 might be SocialNumber and my daughter SSN :: 12.3456789 and son SSN will be 33-4444444
```

Tags: SSN,SocialNumber

RegeX:

```
    String pattern = "(SSN|SocialNumber)([^\\d]*)(\\d{3}[.-]\\d{3}[.-]\\d{3})|"
                    +"(\\d{3}[.-]\\d{3}[.-]\\d{3})([^\\d]*)(SSN|SocialNumber) | " 
                    +"(SSN|SocialNumber)[^\\d]*(\\d{2}[.-]\\d{6})|"
                    + "(\\d{2}[.-]\\d{6})([^\\d]*(SSN|SocialNumber))";
```

Code Output:

```
SSN is 111-111-111
222-222-222 might be SocialNumber and my daughter SSN 
 SSN will be 33-444444
```

If you see the above output it captures John, his wife and Son SSN correctly based on Tags(SSN|SocialNumber) but daughter SSN is missed. Please Assist

Expected Output:

```
SSN is 111-111-111
222-222-222 might be SocialNumber
SSN :: 12.3456789
SSN will be 33-4444444
```

Comment: Don't use regex? Regular expressions are great at parsing [regular grammar](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_grammar) (an extremely well-defined type of [formal grammar](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Formal_grammar)). So **if** you really need to deal with freeform input and unknown word distances, write an actual parser: tokenize and index your input, marking each token that is a valid potentially-symbol-interspersed SSN as a evaluation target, and then look for whether it has "words that describe an SSN" near them.

Comment: What are the rules to match something before and after?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try below regex:

```
SSN is | is SocialNumber|\d{3}-\d{3}-\d{3}|\d{2}-\d{7}|\d{2}\.\d{7}
```

- I have basically taken 2 strings: `SSN is`  and  `is SocialNumber`.
- And 3 formats: `ddd-ddd-ddd` or `dd-ddddddd` or `dd.ddddddd`

Test [here](https://regex101.com/r/AZmWl5/1).

Comment: @ Homer, we cant predict the word after/before Tags. It can be any thing. So i am capturing digits before or after the Tag.

Comment: "The field is freetext user can enter SSN in any format" suggests that the only possible definition for the SSN itself is `[\d\W]{9}`, after which you'd still need to do additional work: what the op wants is not something that regex were invented to do.